# Visualizing Database Schema

Tags: sql-server, erd

I am not a DBA, but an end user that mashes together data from various databases within my company to generate insights.

When I first encounter a new (to me) database, I spend time scrolling through the tables/views/columns in SSMS or Power Query to understand what data is in the database, and how it is structured.  This is a manual process, and I may overlook key tables when scrolling through a long list.

Is there an easy tool that can scan a database and visually represent the database structure?  I believe older versions of Visio could reverse engineer a database and generate a database model/entity relationship diagram, but the current version does not. If it matters, the databases in question are all MSSQL

Comment: If you're interested in spending some fairly serious money, [SAP Power Designer](https://global.sap.com/campaign/ne/sybase/powerdesigner16_da/index.epx?kNtBzmUK9zU) has a very powerful interface that is designed for, among other things, reverse engineering various flavors of databases, including SQL Server.

Answer (score 13):

In SSMS you can easily create diagrams showing the relationships between tables. The basic steps are:

1. Connect to the database server
2. Expand the `Databases` folder
3. Expand the folder for the database you're investigating.
4. Right click on the `Database Diagrams` folder.

   a. Select `Install Diagram Support` if needed
5. Select `New Database Diagram`
6. In the wizard add any tables you're interested in.
7. Take the appropriate next step:

   a. Curse the previous DBA/Developer that generated this mess.

   b. Thank your deity of choice for the blessing of a well structured/modeled database.

   c. Shrug your shoulders and tell yourself this is manageable.